# Google Site Map & Mod Re-Write

Tags: sitemap

Evening, I have a framework which I built myself to easily add pages and alter my site. The site map is also dynamically written depending on the data stored in certain objects within the framework.

Problem being the sitemap gets rejected by Google Webmaster Tools saying along the lines of;

> URL not allowed
>   This url is not allowed for a Sitemap at this location.
>
> URL:
>   http://www.actwebdesigns.com/web_design_mansfield
>   Problem detected on: Aug 24, 2010

Can anyone advise on why it's saying this?

regards,

phil

Comment: sorry, remove this, realised the site map hadn't updated since moved over from .com to .co.uk